# Does turning off fsync in PostgreSQL can corrupt all the database or only the specific table I'm working with

Tags: database, postgresql, timescaledb

I'm working with `PostgreSQL` and I read a lot about the unrecommended option of disabling fsync (`fsync = off`).
However, it was not clear to me if disabling the `fsync` option may corrupt all the database or only the specific table I'm working with.

Does anyone here can share from his experience or share an official link that's clarify this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Joseph

Comment: Your entire cluster, not just one table or one database, just everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fsync` is required to persist data to disk:

- the WAL (transaction log), so that committed transactions are on disk and no data modification takes place before it is logged in WAL
- the data files during a checkpoint

Both WAL and checkpoints are cluster-wide concepts, so your whole cluster will be broken after a crash with `fsync` disabled.

Don't touch that dial!

Comment: Does working with 'unlogged table' would be a better solution for me instead of turning off the 'fsync' ? (I'm ok with loosing the data of the current table I'm working with in a case of failure)

Comment: With an unlogged table, you are guaranteed to end up with an empty table after crash recovery. That's probably not what you want.